# Draw a rectangle scaled to zoom level in Gmap API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

At the moment I have a function that draws a rectangle of approximately 2km large with this code :

```
var radius = 0.02;
        var c = Math.cos(location.lat()* Math.PI / 180);
        rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat()-c*radius/2, location.lng()-radius/2),
            new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat()+c*radius/2, location.lng()+radius/2)));

        rectangle.setMap(map);
```

At zoom level 1 the rectangle is too small, and too wide at zoom level 18.

I would prefer if the rectangle size was a percentage of the map size, in order to be always visible whatever the zoom level at creation. Could you please help me to find information about how to achieve it ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : I found a solution :

```
var scale = Math.pow(2,map.getZoom());

        rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(((location.lat()* scale) - 50)/ scale, ((location.lng()* scale) - 75)/ scale),
            new google.maps.LatLng(((location.lat()* scale) + 50)/ scale, ((location.lng()* scale) + 75)/ scale)));

        rectangle.setMap(map);
```

if it is of any use to other people